# how to add or remove class from html elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to add class on a current `<a></a>` and wanted to remove that active class from other `<a></a>`. i was trying

[MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwzu738a/)

HTML

```
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#" class="active">
    Home
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    About
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    Service
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');`

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I feel Invoking _3_ methods is little expensive..IMO..

Comment: @Rayon : just an alternative method... :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan – Yeah.. One-liner ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('ul li a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  $('ul li a').removeClass('active')
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#" class="active">
    Home
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    About
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    Service
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
jQuery
```

You can remove all the active class from anchor then add the active class to clicked anchor

Answer (score 1):

`a` element in your code has no sibling in parent `li`

Use `$('ul li a.active')` selector and remove all `active` classes and then apply `active` class over current element

```js
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('ul li a.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="active">
    Home
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
    About
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
    Service
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the a tag elements which are not the direct sibling but the children of the current a tag element parent siblings.

use the below code to find the **a tag elements** which are the children of the clicked **a tag** element's parent **li** sibling

```
$(this).addClass('active').parent("li").siblings("li").children("a").removeClass('active');
```

updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lwzu738a/1/